# Using function in where clause: how many times is the function evaluated?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I use a function in a where clause, how many times is it evaluated?  I'm wondering about the effect on performance in more complicated queries.

example:

```
select 
col1, col2, expirationDate
from someTable
where expirationDate > getdate()
```

versus

```
declare @today date = getdate()
select 
col1, col2, expirationDate
from someTable
where expirationDate > @today
```

Comment: Please consider marking an answer to this question.  If you need more information follow up can continue in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

[It is only evaluated once.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx)

FTA:

> SQL Server has a concept called “runtime constants” where some expressions are pulled out of the tree and executed before rows are fetched.  The result is cached and re-used in all places within the query. 
>   ...
>   getdate() is one

Additional reading over at [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18461/28523)

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Sql server will evaluate GETDATE() as deterministic execution, and will evaluate GETDATE() once, and not for each row.

**Edit**: I think I'm mistaken -- GETDATE() is always non-deterministic. 
Rather, GETDATE() is treated as a runtime constant function within a query.
[Here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2008/03/01/when-a-function-is-indeed-a-constant.aspx) is an article explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

**As a rule you should not include the columns you are filtering in a function.**

Since you have not enclosed `expirationDate` within any function the value of your column `expirationDate` is accessible to query optimizer at compile time and hence it will not affect performance (i.e. if you have an index on `expirationDate` )

For [example](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3204/avoid-using-functions-in-where-clause/), If `expirationDate` was enlosed within some function say `DATEPART`, then the compiler will not choose an index over that column even if it exists.

Also, as pointed out above `GETDATE()` is treated as a [runtime constant function](https://sithulatt.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/getdate-in-where-clause/) wherein expressions are pulled out of the tree and executed before rows are fetched. The result is then cached and re-used in all places within the query