# At what point in the query processing lifecycle are runtime constant functions evaluated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that holds data about events in my application and I want to process these events in order, one at a time. Rows are created (inserted into the table) from a trigger on a different table. Rows are picked for processing using an UPDATE TOP 1...ORDER BY Id style query. Common sense says that a row must be created before it can be picked, but during load testing very occasionally the datetime recorded for the picking is BEFORE the datetime recorded for the create.

After Googling for a while my best guess as to what is going on (based mainly on a blog from [Connor Cunningham](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/rand-and-other-runtime-constant-functions-redux/) linked from [Using function in where clause: how many times is the function evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853501/using-function-in-where-clause-how-many-times-is-the-function-evaluated)) is that the execution of the create and the pick queries overlap and sysutcdatetime() is evaluated at the *start* of query execution before waits causes the queries to finish in the opposite order to which they started. Something roughly like this (time moving downwards)

```
---------------------------------------------------
|Create Query            |Pick Query              |
===================================================
|                        |query start             |
---------------------------------------------------
|                        |evaluate sysutcdatetime |
---------------------------------------------------
|query start             |wait/block              |
---------------------------------------------------
|evaluate sysutcdatetime |wait/block              |
---------------------------------------------------
|insert rows using       |wait/block              |
|sysutcdatetime value    |                        |
|as Create timestamp     |                        |
---------------------------------------------------
|transaction commits     |wait/block              |
---------------------------------------------------
|                        |update top 1 using      |
|                        |sysutcdatetime value as |
|                        |Pick timestamp          |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone confirm when runtime constant functions are evaluated? Or provide an alternative explanation for how the datetime recorded for the picking could be BEFORE the datetime recorded for the create?

Just to be clear, I'm looking to understand the behaviour I'm seeing, not for ways to change my schema/code to make the problem go away. My fix for now is to remove the `(PickedAt >= CreatedAt)` check constraint.

---

For completeness, the relevant parts of my event table are;

```
create table dbo.JobInstanceEvent (
    Id int identity not null constraint PK_JobInstanceEvent primary key,
    JobInstanceId int not null constraint FK_JobInstanceEvent_JobInstance foreign key references dbo.JobInstance (Id),
    JobInstanceStateCodeOld char(4) not null constraint FK_JobInstanceEvent_JobInstanceState1 foreign key references ref.JobInstanceState (Code),
    JobInstanceStateCodeNew char(4) not null constraint FK_JobInstanceEvent_JobInstanceState2 foreign key references ref.JobInstanceState (Code),
    JobInstanceEventStateCode char(4) not null constraint FK_JobInstance_JobInstanceEventState foreign key references ref.JobInstanceEventState (Code),
    CreatedAt datetime2 not null,
    PickedAt datetime2 null,
    FinishedAt datetime2 null,
    constraint CK_JobInstanceEvent_PickedAt check (PickedAt >= CreatedAt),
    constraint CK_JobInstanceEvent_FinishedAt check (FinishedAt >= PickedAt),
    constraint CK_JobInstanceEvent_PickedAt_FinishedAt check (PickedAt is null and FinishedAt is null or
                                                              PickedAt is not null) -- this covers the allowable combinations of PickedAt/FinishedAt
)
```

The SQL statement that creates the new rows is;

```
insert dbo.JobInstanceEvent (JobInstanceId, JobInstanceStateCodeOld, JobInstanceStateCodeNew, JobInstanceEventStateCode, CreatedAt)
    select
        i.Id as JobInstanceId,
        d.JobInstanceStateCode as JobInstanceStateCodeOld,
        i.JobInstanceStateCode as JobInstanceStateCodeNew,
        'CRTD' as JobInstanceEventStateCode,
        sysutcdatetime() as CreatedAt
    from
        inserted i
            inner join deleted d on d.Id = i.Id
    where
        i.JobInstanceStateCode <> d.JobInstanceStateCode and -- the state has changed and
        i.JobInstanceStateCode in ('SUCC', 'FAIL')           -- the new state is either success or failure.
```

The SQL statement that picks a row is;

```
    ; with cte as (
        select top 1 
            jie.Id,
            jie.JobInstanceId,
            jie.JobInstanceStateCodeOld,
            jie.JobInstanceStateCodeNew,
            jie.JobInstanceEventStateCode,
            jie.PickedAt
        from
            dbo.JobInstanceEvent jie
        where
            jie.JobInstanceEventStateCode = 'CRTD'
        order by
            jie.Id
    )
    update cte set 
        JobInstanceEventStateCode = 'PICK', 
        PickedAt = sysutcdatetime()
    output 
        inserted.Id,
        inserted.JobInstanceId,
        inserted.JobInstanceStateCodeOld,
        inserted.JobInstanceStateCodeNew
    into 
        @PickedJobInstanceEvent
```

I'm using SQL Server 2016 but I don't think this is a version specific issue.

Comment: Sequnce of Insert/Update and their places are not clear.`insert dbo.JobInstanceEvent`  is happending inside `Trigger` .Right ? From which place `Update` is firing and when for given row.

Comment: [runtime constants are evaluated before the query starts processing rows and the result is cached.](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/09/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.html)

Comment: @KumarHarsh Ignore the trigger part, what's relevant is that the INSERT and the UPDATE are in seperate sessions.

Comment: @MartinSmith The line from the explanation section of that page "These runtime constants are evaluated before the query starts processing rows and the result is cached." is the sort of thing I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> explanation for how the datetime recorded for the picking could be
>   BEFORE the datetime recorded for the create?

You could simulate the behavior of the create/pick query diagram by using the following (two ssms windows, for the create and pickup queries)

Another contributing factor is [the time accuracy of windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859480/why-does-my-sql-server-trigger-write-two-records-with-the-same-time-stamp-from-d). In a highly concurrent system, blocking and waits will definitely occur and picked dates could be at least the same or a few millisecs before the creation dates (if pickup queries have to wait for the creation of new rows).

```
create table dbo.atest
(
id int identity primary key clustered,
colA char(500) default('a'),
createddate datetime2(4) default(sysdatetime()),
pickeddate datetime2(4)
)
go

--rows already picked up
insert into dbo.atest(colA, createddate,pickeddate) 
values
('a', '20200405 12:00', '20200406 10:00'), 
('b', '20200405 12:00', '20200406 10:10'), 
('c', '20200405 12:00', '20200406 10:20'),
('d', '20200405 12:00', '20200406 10:30');

--create a new row..to be picked up
begin transaction  -- ...
update dbo.atest --..query start | wait block
set colA = colA

waitfor delay '00:00:40'
--during the waitfor delay, in another window(SSMS)
/*

--this will wait(blocking) for the delay and the insert and commit...
update a
set pickeddate = sysdatetime()
from
(
select top (1) *
from dbo.atest
where pickeddate is null
order by id 
) as a;

--insertion happened after the update was fired, picked<created
select *
from dbo.atest
where pickeddate < createddate;

*/   

--create new row
insert into dbo.atest(colA) values('e')

commit transaction
go

--drop table dbo.atest
```

You could prevent pickdate < createdate by incorporating a condition in the select/pickup query:

```
    from
        dbo.JobInstanceEvent jie
    where
        jie.JobInstanceEventStateCode = 'CRTD'
        and jie.CreatedAt < /*= ?*/ sysutcdatetime()
    order by
        jie.Id
```

Comment: That is an excellent demo of my problem (thankyou for your effort) but it doesn't address the actual question - the blog @MartinSmith linked in his comment on the question confirms "These runtime constants are evaluated before the query starts processing rows and the result is cached.". Timer resolution isn't the issue here as I have reliable times, but in an unexpected order.

Comment: @RhysJones ,Your actual question has notihng to do with your actual problem.You have almost concurrent like situation between Create date and pickdate.Optimizing query may address the issue but that is not reliable way to address such situation.One such way seem OK to me.